Is there a (mostly) comprehensive list of cursed magical items?
A comprehensive list of cursed magical items is valuable to any GM as a reference. If the list only references official, published material, it will be finite and objective.

I’m voting to close this question because it is a list based question that would be practically impossible to answer even if weren't purely a list.

It isn't a great question, but it's a pretty small list.

I'm not seeing a question that defines what is being asked for here. I'm seeing a statement with a question mark at the end.

Note (@TimothyAWiseman) that a question whose answer is likely a list isn't necessarily a (bad) "list question" in Stack parlance: see RPG FAQs (1, 2) and meta.SE on the topic.

@TimothyAWiseman Regardless of the topic: Do you have anything to do with "VGA Planets"?

@nitsua60 Fair point and I should have been more precise in my comment. That said, I do believe this falls within the bad list question category in my opinion.

@Flynxer I've never heard of that before.

@TimothyAWiseman Never mind, a "Tim Wiseman" was the programmer of that game .. a long time ago. Sorry to bother you.

@TimothyAWiseman, Is there a way to improve the question? Or, can you say why you think it's a "bad list question"?

@nonymous It is bad mostly because it doesn't ask for the solution to an actual problem. It literally asks for just a list of things that exist. Also, it is the kind of thing that goes out of date quickly. While as nitsua's links point out, that is not always bad by itself (most technical questions go out of date eventually), it is certainly not a good thing. I want to be clear that nothing I say is meant as an attack on you in any way, but I don't think this type of question is a good match for this site.

@TimothyAWiseman, No worries. I didn't take it personally, and I got the answer I was seeking. There are just a lot of "list based questions" that already exist on the site, and I was wondering what made this one different. It seems to me that the list won't change much, if at all, because 2014 material is essentially deprecated. But, I didn't realize that asking for a resource like that was a bad match for the site.

@nonymous I didn’t vote to close, but I did downvote, because it does not appear that you made any effort to research this for yourself.

@nonymous I voted to reopen it fwiw. I don't think it shows any research effort as Thomas said, but I don't think it should be closed.

It's not something for which you can show much research effort. "Hey, I did some searches and didn't come up with anything organized...", or "I found x,y,z cursed items, are there more?", is about all you can do. Even the D&D Beyond filtered search provides items that aren't cursed in the strict sense. But, it's valuable information to know what kind of ratio cursed::uncursed exists, and what kinds of curses are typical for homebrew guidelines. I'm not concerned with it being closed. But, thanks @SeriousBri, I think you're good people.

You can filter for cursed magic items on D&D Beyond, the official site for D&D 5e rules. Here is the list as of posting this:

Armor of Vulnerability (BR)
Axe of the Dwarvish Lords (DMG)
Berserker Axe (BR)
Blasted Goggles (BoMT)
Book of Vile Darkness (DMG/KGV)
Bracelet of Rock Magic (TYP)
Demon Armor (BR)
Eye and Hand of Vecna (DMG)
Hellhound Cloak (TYP)
Javelin of Backbiting (TYP)
Loadstone (TYP)
Potion of Poison (DMG)
Pyxis of Pandemonium (MOT)
Scorpion Armor (ToA)
Shard of Xeluan (KGV)
Shield of Missile Attraction (BR)
Shield of the Tortoise (BoMT)
Shrieking Greaves (BoMT)
Spear of Backbiting (TYP)
Staff of the Forgotten One (ToA)
Stone of Ill Luck (TYP)
Sword of Kas (DMG)
Sword of Vengeance (DMG)
Voidwalker Armor (BoMT)
Wand of Orcus (DMG)


Currently 26 items, from what I counted. It is a smallish list as SeriousBri mentioned :) But is D&D Beyond reliable in terms of that the link you posted won't change?

A potion of poison actually killed a PC in my group earlier this year, our DM laughed like crazy.
